# Make HTML Div with display: none visible again + Loading Image before <li>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a list, which shows up, after pressing a button.

So I added this code:

```
<div id="divCheckbox" style="display: none;">
<ul style="list-style-type>
<li>Apples<li>
<li>Potatos</li>
<li>Dank Memes</li>
<li>Holla Holla get Dolla</li>
<li>420 everyday</li>
<li>Finished</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

To make it visible again, I tried using this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("divCheckbox");
element.style.visibility='visible';
```

This doesnt work, the object remains invisible.
But the changes are made, and the element exists, I checked that with document.getElementById

Also I want the list to "load" so each element has a little loading animation infront of it, after 1 second it goes to a tick and goes green, I have no idea how to make that, but i think its something about CSS. I just need to know how I can set an image infront of a li element with javascript.

What am I missing?

Comment: Visibility and display are different properties, so you change the visibility property but display remains none

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @rorschach - change your JS code to this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("divCheckbox");
element.style.display='block';
```

Also - this line `<ul style="list-style-type>` - make sure you close your quote there to `<ul style="list-style-type">`

Answer (score 1):

If the element's `display` is set to `none` at first then screwing around with `visibility` has no effect - you need to change `display` to `block` or whatever is appropriate.